# Reading values from config file in ReactApp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, project-structure, config.json

We can create reactApp with `create-react-app` command. It will give a folder structure as follows:
|_ public

|_ src

|_ package.json

|_ README.md

Normally, for javascript we specify values via config.json. Can someone help me to find out what is the standard way to put config file in reactApp. should it be under src or separate folder?

Comment: What values, what config.json ? If it is a random config file. you can probably just put it wherever you like

Comment: In my react app, I am fecthing data from specified url. Now I hard-coded it withing the .js file. I need to change it to .config file so that the url can be changed after building the app also.

Comment: you can then put that config file wherever you like

Comment: But, after building the app (using npm run build) , we cannot change it. right?